# Failed to pull image "velero/velero-plugin-for-gcp:v1.1.0" while installing Velero in GKE Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, backup, google-kubernetes-engine, velero

I'm trying to install and configure Velero for kubernetes backup. I have followed the [link](https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero-plugin-for-gcp#setup) to configure it in my GKE cluster. The installation went fine, but velero is not working.

I am using google cloud shell for running all my commands (I have installed and configured velero client in my google cloud shell)

On further inspection on velero deployment and velero pods, I found out that it is not able to pull the image from the docker repository.

```
kubectl get pods -n velero
NAME                      READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
velero-5489b955f6-kqb7z   0/1     Init:ErrImagePull   0          20s
```

Error from velero pod (kubectl describe pod) (output redacted for readability - only relevant info shown below)

```
    Events:
  Type     Reason     Age               From                                                  Message
  ----     ------     ----              ----                                                  -------
  Normal   Scheduled  38s               default-scheduler                                     Successfully assigned velero/velero-5489b955f6-kqb7z to gke-gke-cluster1-default-pool-a354fba3-8674
  Warning  Failed     22s               kubelet, gke-gke-cluster1-default-pool-a354fba3-8674  Failed to pull image "velero/velero-plugin-for-gcp:v1.1.0": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
  Warning  Failed     22s               kubelet, gke-gke-cluster1-default-pool-a354fba3-8674  Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff    21s               kubelet, gke-gke-cluster1-default-pool-a354fba3-8674  Back-off pulling image "velero/velero-plugin-for-gcp:v1.1.0"
  Warning  Failed     21s               kubelet, gke-gke-cluster1-default-pool-a354fba3-8674  Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling    8s (x2 over 37s)  kubelet, gke-gke-cluster1-default-pool-a354fba3-8674  Pulling image "velero/velero-plugin-for-gcp:v1.1.0"
```

Command used to install velero: (some of the values are given as variables)

```
velero install \
     --provider gcp \
     --plugins velero/velero-plugin-for-gcp:v1.1.0 \
     --bucket $storagebucket \
     --secret-file ~/velero-backup-storage-sa-key.json
```

Velero Version

```
velero version
Client:
        Version: v1.4.2
        Git commit: 56a08a4d695d893f0863f697c2f926e27d70c0c5
<error getting server version: timed out waiting for server status request to be processed>
```

GKE version

```
v1.15.12-gke.2
```

Comment: That seems like a firewall blocking connection to docker registry? Is it happening only with this image from docker registry?

Comment: Isn't this a Private Cluster ?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu it is happening only with this image. I am able to deploy other images without any issues..
Looking at the describe pod, I can see the below: 
Containers:
  velero:
    Container ID:
    Image:         velero/velero:v1.4.2

Comment: @Sreesan Other public images from docker hub registry works?

Comment: Image: velero/velero:v1.4.2  (Is this issue because of the image url?) velero has created custom resource definitions for deploying this

Comment: @mario this is a private cluster but I can deploy other services without any issues (for eg: I have deployed nginx successfully)

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu yes, they works without any issues...for example, I deployed nginx without any issue using the command "kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Isn't this a Private Cluster ? – mario 31 mins ago*
>
> *@mario this is a private cluster but I can deploy other services without any issues (for eg: I have deployed nginx successfully) –
> Sreesan 15 mins ago*

Well, this is a [know limitation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#docker_hub) of [**GKE Private Clusters**](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters). As you can read in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#docker_hub):

> #### Can't pull image from public Docker Hub
>
> **Symptoms**
>
> A Pod running in your cluster displays a warning in  `kubectl describe`  such as  `Failed to pull image: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)`
>
> **Potential causes**
>
> Nodes in a private cluster do not have outbound access to the public
> internet. They have limited access to Google APIs and services,
> including Container Registry.
>
> **Resolution**
>
> You cannot fetch images directly from Docker Hub. Instead, use images
> hosted on Container Registry. Note that while Container Registry's
> [Docker Hub
> mirror](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/using-dockerhub-mirroring)
> is accessible from a private cluster, it should not be exclusively
> relied upon. The mirror is only a cache, so images are periodically
> removed, and a private cluster is not able to fall back to Docker Hub.

You can also compare it with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62382321/gke-image-pull-errors-for-specific-public-docker-hub-images/62475193#62475193) answer.

It can be easily verified on your own by making a simple experiment. Try to run two different nginx deployments. First based on image `nginx` (which equals to `nginx:latest`) and the second one based on `nginx:1.14.2`.

While the first scenario is perfectly feasible because the `nginx:latest` image can be pulled from **Container Registry's Docker Hub mirror** which is accessible from a private cluster, any attempt of pulling `nginx:1.14.2` will fail which you'll see in `Pod` events. It happens because the **kubelet** is not able to find this version of the image in **GCR** and it tries to pull it from public docker registry (`https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/`), which in **Private Clusters** is not possible. *"The mirror is only a cache, so images are periodically removed, and a private cluster is not able to fall back to Docker Hub."* - as you can read in docs.

If you still have doubts, just `ssh` into your node and try to run following commands:

```
curl https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/

curl https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/
```

While the first one works perfectly, the second one will eventually fail:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to registry-1.docker.io port 443: Connection timed out
```

Reason ? - *"Nodes in a private cluster do not have outbound access to the public internet."*

#### Solution ?

You can search what is currently available in **GCR** [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/google-containers).

In many cases you should be able to get the required image if you don't specify it's exact version (by default `latest` tag is used). While it can help with `nginx`, unfortunatelly no version of [velero/velero-plugin-for-gcp](https://hub.docker.com/r/velero/velero-plugin-for-gcp) is currently available in Google Container Registry's Docker Hub mirror.

[Granting private nodes outbound internet access](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#private-nodes-outbound) by using [Cloud NAT](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview#NATwithGKE) seems the only reasonable solution that can be applied in your case.

Comment: mario thanks for the detailed explanation for the issue and the possible solution..I solved the final part of the problem (ie, using velero images in private gke clusters) without using cloud NAT. Instead I used gcr.io for storing the images. I followed the steps in given in https://velero.io/docs/main/on-premises/ to save the velero images in my private gcr  (not the gcr mirror) and then used that private images to install velero in my private gke cluster

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help. Uploading an image to private gcr is also a great solution!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by realizing that version of:

```
velero/velero-plugin-for-gcp
```

is not following the version of:

```
velero/velero
```

For example, now  latest versions are:
`velero/velero:v1.9.1` and `velero/velero-plugin-for-gcp:v1.5.0`